# How can I get investigation evidence of Rapid7 insight IDR with rest API?

Tags: api, rest, rapid7

May I know how I can get Rapid7 idr investigation details with REST API, for example evidence?
I know investigation details can be obtained on insightIDR GUI. However for API, there is only a list investigation API - "GET /idr/v1/investigations/". I wonder if there is an API can retrieve detailed investigation information(evidence) with investigation id.

Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on Rapid7 IDR API integration. My client hopes to retrieve detailed investigation information with REST API, but after checking public IDR API document, I cannot find an API which can retrieve investigation details. One of my friends told me that Rapid7 has /restricted/ API with which I can get detailed investigation evidence information.